# Want to check a windows tag for jpeg using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

Ok so I put a tag on one of my photos using Windows photo gallery.
I want to check this tag using PIL.

I do:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('myimg.jpg')
exif_data = img._getexif()
print(exif_data) # outputs a lot of hex
```

But just see a bunch hex text.  How do I get the new tag I have added to the photo?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a bunch of text. I see some code, but that code doesn't print any text. What did you do to see that text, and what text did you see?

Comment: Where did you find out about the `_getexif()` function and what tag are you adding?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the EXIF dictionary, which is keyed on EXIF numeric tags.

You'll either need to know the numeric tag of the entry you are looking for or use the `PIL.ExifTags` mapping to translate the numbers to human-readable strings:

```
exif = {PIL.ExifTags.TAGS.get(k, k): v
            for k, v in img._getexif().iteritems()}
```

You'll still need to figure out *which* tagname to use.

```
print exif['exif_tag_you_are_looking_for']
```